# Trigger an HTML event when page is acessed from outside (another domain)

Tags: html, blogger

There's a greeting loader that appears for some seconds on the homepage of my site. but i don't want it repeating it everytime the user comes to the home.

```
<div id='sliderloader'>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
        <img src='Rf8YpZW.jpg' style='z-index:-1;position:absolute;margin-top:-300px;'/>
        <img src='/assets/manivel60.gif' style='position:relative;margin-top:-121px;margin-left:512px;'/>
    </b:if>
    <div id='progressbg'>
        <div id='loader'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's already set to not repeat in subsequent pages, but every time I go to home the loader comes again.

Any idea of how to make this whole code happen just once? (When the home is accessed from inside the page, and appear when accessed from outside.)

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want to turn off the greeting when coming back to your home page from other pages on your site, or for subsequent visits by a user no matter where they are coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the greeting loader to appear when a user navigates to your home page from a page outside your website, write some JavaScript that checks the referrer and compares it to your URL, displaying the loader only for new users:

```
if (document.referrer.indexOf(location.protocol + "//" + location.host) === 0) {
    document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
} else {
    document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'block';
}
```